# How to make a reaction disappear after a certain amount of reactions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I want to make a poll command, where I use the command, and when the reaction reaches a certain amount of reactions it (the reaction) gets deleted. That would be useful to see who wins if you understand me.

That's what I'm using right now for only adding a reaction.

```js
bot.on('message', msg => {
    if(msg.content === "memes"){
        msg.react("")
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [reaction collectors](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=createReactionCollector) to collect user reactions on a message. The collector has options like `maxUsers` that you can use to set the maximum number of users to react. Once it's reached, the `collector.on('end')` fires, so you can use it to get the number of users reacted, etc.

You can remove the reactions using `message.reactions.removeAll();`

Check the snippet below:

```js
if (message.content === 'memes') {
  const EMOJI = '';
  const filter = (reaction, user) =>
    reaction.emoji.name === EMOJI && !user.bot;
  const collector = message.createReactionCollector(filter, {
    // optional, the maximum time in ms the collector collects reactions
    time: 10000,
    // maximum number of users to react
    // it includes the bot's reaction too
    maxUsers: 3,
  });

  message.react(EMOJI);

  collector.on('collect', (reaction, user) => {
    // it fires every time someone reacts to the message
    console.log('collected', reaction);
  });

  collector.on('end', async (collected, reason) => {
    const reaction = collected.get(EMOJI);

    if (!reaction) {
      return message.channel.send('Oops, there were no reactions');
    }

    // it includes the bot too
    const allUsers = await reaction.users.fetch();
    // collection of users who reacted to the message, bot removed
    const users = allUsers.filter((user) => user != client.user);

    message.channel.send(
      `Poll has ended because of ${reason}. Received ${users.size} reactions.`
    );
    message.channel.send(
      `Users reacted: ${users.array().join(', ')}`
    );

    // remove reactions
    message.reactions.removeAll();
  });
}
```

If you want to have an array of emojis, you can use an `EMOJIS` array instead:

```js
if (message.content === 'memes') {
  const EMOJIS = ['', ''];
  const filter = (reaction, user) =>
    EMOJIS.includes(reaction.emoji.name) && !user.bot;
  const collector = message.createReactionCollector(filter, {
    time: 10000,
    maxUsers: 3,
  });

  EMOJIS.forEach((emoji) => message.react(emoji));

  collector.on('collect', (reaction, user) => {
    // it fires every time someone reacts to the message
  });

  collector.on('end', async (collected, reason) => {
    if (!collected.size) {
      message.reactions.removeAll();
      return message.channel.send('Oops, there were no reactions');
    }

    // you can use the collected reactions any way you want
    console.log(collected);

    // remove reactions
    message.reactions.removeAll();
  });
}
```

Comment: If I need two reactions I do

```
if (message.content === 'memes') {
  const EMOJI = '';
const EMOJI = '';
```
and the remaining stay like your example?

By the way, thank you for your help!

Comment: How many emojis do you want? Do you want to the bot react with two emojis? It looks like you need an array of `EMOJIS` then. I'll look into this later and update my answer ;)